# VBA Excel copy and paste from different workbook if condtion is met

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automatically copy a set of data based on todays date.
What I want to do is, have the workbook (already open) which i want to copy data, change the date, and it automatically copies the data from a file I get emailed.

Right now I can do that, but now I want to only copy data if Column P is the same value as Cell AV1 (which is also the date) in my original workbook. I've tweaked my code, but it no longer works and I get

> RUNTIME ERROR 9 subscript out of range

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub import()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim rangedate As Range
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("Location of file\.csv") 
    Set rangedate = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("P2:P1000")

    For Each cell In rangedate
        If cell.Value = Workbooks("Original workbook.xlsm").Range("AV1") Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            wb.Range("A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy` should be `cell.EntireRow.Copy`, also `wb.Range("A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues` missing the row number of the `Range` object

Comment: `Workbooks("Original workbook.xlsm").Range("AV1")` is missing a worksheet but if all AV1 contains is the current date then it can be replaced with `Date` (today's date in VBA).

Comment: Apart from what has already been pointed out, you are missing wb #  on wb.Range(“A”) and paste on xlPasteValues....

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help! I took Shai Rado, Jeeped and Irenes help on board and it works! However, this time when I use wb1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:xlValues, it only copies to Range A2 obviously, and then keeps over-riding th at row.

Is there a way to make rangedate read until the last row of the wb2.Sheet(1) and then for wb.Range to post the equivalent over? Thanks for all the help!